# changing regulatory domain for wireless interface giving error

Tags: shell, networking

I tried `iw dev wlp3s0 set reg BO`

command returned success

but actually it is not changing reg

here is the log:

```
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

phy#0 (self-managed)
country IN: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5170 - 5190 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5190 - 5210 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing regulatory domains is restricted in many countries.
and also it is not possible if the driver doesn't support this feature.

if this command doesn't work for you
`iw dev wlp3s0 set reg BO`

then you can try this method

```
git clone https://github.com/robertfoss/wireless-regdb.git
cd wireless-regdb.git
make
# edit db.txt file with your required country
./db2bin.py
# overwrite /lib/crda/regulatory.bin with new generated file
cp regulatory.bin /lib/crda/regulatory.bin
```

> changing frequencies to higher than 12(channel) is not allowed in some
>   countries.use at your own risk.

Comment: overwriting kernel lib file doesn't create any problem?....@Akhil Jalagam

Comment: you should take backup of the original file before replace it. @John